# StimulusReflex: How to change the URL on reflex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pushstate, stimulus-reflex

We are using [StimulusReflex](https://docs.stimulusreflex.com) and want to change the URL on specific reflexes (e.g. using the Browser `pushState` API, e.g. [via cable_ready](https://cableready.stimulusreflex.com/reference/operations/browser-manipulations#push_state) ??).

Is this a common thing with StimulusReflex? Are there good examples somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update the URL using cable ready:

```
class SomeReflexClass
  def your_reflex
    cable_ready.push_state(url: new_url, state: {turbo: true})
  end
end
```

With turbo links setting the state to `turbo: true` was necessary for turbo links to handle the back button correctly, not sure if it still necessary with Turbo Drive